# "the input device is not a TTY" error on git commit in WSL

Tags: git, git-commit, wsl-2, tty, git-config

I am setting up a new development environment which, on the surface, is the same as the environment I have on another computer:

- Windows 10
- WSL running AmazonLinux2
- Windows terminal
- git version 2.40.1

Using the terminal, I've staged a new set of changes, then type:

```bash
git commit -S -m "My commit message here"
```

Which returns this mmessage:

```bash
the input device is not a TTY
```

Checking `git status` shows that the staged changes remain uncommitted.

I've tried:

- Removing `-m` and the message, hoping git will open vim
- Removing the `-S` switch
- Running `--dry-run`
- All permutations of the above
- Configuring git's `core.terminal` setting to `vi` (which I believe is default, but hey, you never know)

When I Google the message, almost all of the results relate to Docker shells, and seem unrelated (most of the answers involve removing or altering the `-it` switches from a `docker exec` command).  I do have Docker running, but the git command is not being run in a Docker instance.

Again, I do not have this issue on another computer with seemingly the same setup.

### Update

I figured out the cause, and have found a way to work around it without actually solving it; see my own answer below.

Again, not a solution, as linting is there for a reason, obviously, but I was able to push up my changes, complete the task, and push off dealing with the error for another day.  The question is still open.

Comment: Does `mount | grep pts` return a result?  I'm hoping "no", which could point us to the root problem.

Comment: `devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)`

Comment: Good to see that you have a workaround.  I'd suggest moving that to an answer, since it *does* solve the *original problem* for you.  We tend to like to keep the questions and answers separate.  You can reference the "workaround" in the question itself, and continue to mention that you are still looking for an answer that solves the problem with GrumPHP.  You can skip the self-accept step, though, since you really *want* a different answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Moved, thank you.  This is my first StackO question, and I appreciate the help with best practices.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution to the cause of the error, but a workaround that allowed  me to continue working.

git is configured on my machine with a preprocessor that runs GrumPHP to lint my code; the TTY error is being thrown by GrumPHP.  I was able to disable it in order to make my commit, but the problem with GrumPHP remains.

For anyone with a similar problem who Googled your way here, if you have preprocessing configured in your commit flow, the scripts will be in the `.git/hooks/` folder of your project.  In my case, I edited `.git/hooks/pre-commit` and `/.git/hooks/commit-msg` and simply commented out the GrumPHP scripts.

Comment: By "preprocessing" do you mean a pre commit hook?

Comment: It sounds like to truly fix the problem, you need to dig a little deeper. Can you run the script directly in your terminal? Does it give the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

GrumpPHP has option for this case :
In the grumphp.yml config file in your project.

```yaml
grumphp:
  git_hook_variables:
    EXEC_GRUMPHP_COMMAND: docker compose exec --no-TTY your-container-name
    ENV: {
      PATH: "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:./bin:./vendor/bin"
    }
```

Even if you don't do your "git commit" in the docker, grumphp need php environment and should be executed in your docker.